# Call Javascript code in Custom Ribbon Action for office 365

Tags: javascript, office-365, ribbon, custom-actions, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to call my javascript code in custom ribbon action in SharePoint online. I tried
this code.

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
        <CustomAction Id="6e661d80-ffa2-4460-b4d9-5b88cd1cbdf6.RibbonCustomAction1"
                      RegistrationType="List"
                      RegistrationId="{$ListId:Lists/Employee;}"
                      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
                      Sequence="10001"
                      Title="Invoke &apos;RibbonCustomAction1&apos; action">
          <CommandUIExtension>
            <CommandUIDefinitions>
              <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
                <Button Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.RibbonCustomAction1Button"
                        Alt="Request RibbonCustomAction1"
                        Sequence="100"
                        Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                        LabelText="Request RibbonCustomAction1"
                        TemplateAlias="o1"
                        Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
                        Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" />
              </CommandUIDefinition>
            </CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIHandlers>
              <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                                CommandAction="javascript:alert('hii');"/>
            </CommandUIHandlers>
          </CommandUIExtension >
        </CustomAction>
      </Elements>
```

but while deploying this code give me error.I tried the same code in Sandbox solution and it is working fine.

[image]

Please let me know if any one of you also faced this issue

Comment: Copy/paste typo for the closing Elements missing the last > ? Other than that, maybe try another sequence number... the schema looks fine. I use javascript call like that in a custom action and it's working.

Comment: yes that is copy paste error.I tried by changing sequence number but still it does not worked.can you please place your code here.

Comment: Try to put a different RegistrationId, put your list GUID hardcoded or 100 for custom list

Comment: sorry for late reply.I have tried by changing RegistrationId both by 100 for custom list and list GUID but still it is displaying same error

Comment: What you are using? SharePoint App?

Comment: yes i am using sharepoint hosted app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the following approach.

- Create a Sandbox solution rather then creating the SharePoint App
- Deploy your solution to your SharePoint Online Solution Gallery
- Activate your solution
- Activate the feature of your newly activated solution

I know this is not the ultimate solution but this solution worked at my end.

Let me know whether it helped you or not.

Comment: Sandbox solutions are obsolete according to Microsoft